# Data Analysis in Java, servlet to JS array, and then graphing using d3.js

Tags: java, node.js, servlets, d3.js, data-analysis

I'm building a program to read in large csv files, ~ a few million rows by 15 columns, and ran into browser memory issues when loading data to the browser while using javascript.

Now, I'm thinking about loading data and performing analysis in Java, opening a servlet and sending smaller datafiles to javascript and then graphing using d3.js. Does this sound like a better strategy or am I missing something? I've briefly looked into writing JavaScript outside the browser using node.js to avoid the browser memory issues, but am unsure as to which is a better strategy for datasets this large. Thanks and any insight will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, sounds like a good strategy and one I use fairly often.

Comment: Question's too broad for StackOverflow but your approach is sound.  With that much data, you might want to throw a database in the mix, otherwise you'll have to hold it in memory on your server or continually read and parse files on the server.  Java or Node will do the job on the server side easy and I'd chose the one you are more comfortable with (unless, of course, you are looking to learn something new).